# extract JSON from a javascript code using php

Tags: javascript, php, json, regex

I want to extract JSON between `var data = {` and `A.trigger` ...

```
$images_script = <<<EOM

P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){
    var data = {
                'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61z4lNt%2BjZL._SL1300_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31%2BSEYm%2B8QL._SS40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31%2BSEYm%2B8QL.jpg",
"main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61z4lNt%2BjZL._SY355_.jpg":[355,355],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61z4lNt%2BjZL._SY450_.jpg":[450,450],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61z4lNt%2BjZL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61z4lNt%2BjZL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61z4lNt%2BjZL._SX522_.jpg":[522,522]},"variant":"MAIN"}]},
                'colorToAsin': {'initial': {}},
                'holderRatio': 1.0,
                'holderMaxHeight': 700,
                'weblabs' : {}
                };
    A.trigger('P.AboveTheFold'); // trigger ATF event.
    return data;
});        
EOM;
```

I have tried

```
$startsAt = strpos($out, "var data = {") + strlen("var data = {");
$endsAt = strpos($out, "A.trigger", $startsAt);
$result = substr($out, $startsAt, $endsAt - $startsAt);
```

and also have tried

```
preg_match('~var data =(.*?)A.trigger~', $images_script, $output);
```

But I am not able to get that JSON.

Can someone tell me how do I do that?

Comment: how is the json generated?

Comment: what? I am not generating it ... its on the page I am scraping ... I want to extract it using PHP Regex or some other method

Comment: use an html parser then use a javascript parser.

Comment: Extract in sense, as a string in whole or separated as objects?

Comment: I am using a HTML parser ... I do have access to that JS code ... i just want to extract JSON ... I have that JS code in `$images_script` variable ... see question edits

Comment: @ameenulla0007 extract as a string only  ... then I can do `json_decode()` in PHP

Comment: If you extract that as a string you will find it isn't valid JSON. (You'd have to change all the single quotes into double quotes.)

Comment: @nnnnnn its valid ... just replace single-quotes to double-quotes in those keys

Comment: @Umair, "it's valid (if you change it to make it valid)". It's valid _JavaScript_, but not valid _JSON_. Anyway, if you want to reliably parse that you're going to need a full-featured JavaScript parser. I'm not aware of any clean way to do that from PHP.

Comment: my purpose is to get Image links from that JSON ...

Comment: and yes its a valid json you can copy and paste here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @Umair, it is _not_ valid [JSON](http://json.org/). JSON strings _must_ use double quotes, like nnnnnn has said. Your link even says the same: "Error: Strings should be wrapped in double quotes."

Comment: Ahhh man ... I can simply do it using `str_replace("'", '"', $string);`

so valid or invalid JSON is not issue ... I can make it valid ... but issue is how to extract it that is my question

Comment: @Umair, can you? What about `{'foo': 'bar"baz'}` or `{"foo": "bar'baz"}`? You should really be thinking in terms of JavaScript (because that's what you have), not JSON (which you don't). And that's not a simple task. Regular expressions cannot be used to reliably match JavaScript objects or JSON due to their nested `{}` and balanced `"`.

Comment: there can be a simple REGEX to get data between two strings `var data = {` and `A.trigger`  ... this is all I need

Comment: Your regexp will work if you add the `s` option, which allows `.` to match newlines.

Comment: @Chris A fully general solution isn't always needed. He's dealing with Javascript with a specific format -- it uses a particular variable name, it has `A.trigger` affer it, the object properties are known. So he can tailor his solution to the known input format.

Comment: @Umair [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08d5a051b82ff0b13a62343352be9b8aaae61bfe) you have all images parsed as an assoc array, but this will work only when data your page will not change :)

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close with the preg_match attempt, you had just to use the `s` flag (single line flag)

```
preg_match('~var data =(.*?)A.trigger~s', $images_script, $output);
                            Here -----^
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bU0xU1/1)**

**[IDEOne demo](https://ideone.com/p0NjLg)**

Btw, keep in mind that the captured json will contain the `;` at the end since you used `A.trigger` as the boundary

Comment: This works ... I have another JS string .... but that has first word `define("product/data",` and 2nd word `define("athena/analytics-data", null)` i want to get data between these 2 words... how do do that? the regex you psoted does not work with this string

Comment: @Umair is this regex not enough? [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08d5a051b82ff0b13a62343352be9b8aaae61bfe)

Comment: @Umair, that's a different question than the one you posted. You should mark this one as resolved an open a new question.

Comment: Regex should work for all strings ... Means it should be a general solution for "how to get substring between two given strings" ...

Comment: @Umair correct me if I'm wrong... didn't you ask to get the string between `var data = {` and `A.trigger`? That's what I have answered. If you want to get the string between different strings then that's a different question. On the other hand, I you mean that you want to capture multiple string with the same pattern then you have to use `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score -3):

if your data is always the same you can use simple regex like below

but if your website is changing or there are more different pages then you must use somethink else

---

if data var structure isalways the same:

```
preg_match('/\s?data\s?\=\s?(\{[^\;]+\})/i',$images_script,$matches);
$parsed=json_decode(str_replace("'",'"',$matches[1]),true);
```

[php result here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08d5a051b82ff0b13a62343352be9b8aaae61bfe)

o if you want just images with correspponding resolution try [this](https://regex101.com/r/lA6rI3/3)

`\"([^\"]+)\"\s?\:\s?\"(https?\:\/\/[^\"]+)\"`

```
$mathes=[];
preg_match_all('/\"([^\"]+)\"\s?\:\s?\"(https?\:\/\/[^\"]+)\"/im',$your_text,$matches);
```

[php Result is here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/280d638c662f33fa2e21a9bf4268ced40c302637)